# Is there a way to perform if-else using collect in ruby and update an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, collect

```
$days = 25
action_count = [0,0,0]

if $days < 0 
  action_count[0] += 1
elsif $days <= 20
  action_count[1] += 1
else
  action_count[2] += 1
end
```

Can this if-else code be shortened using collect in ruby

Answer (score 4):

I can't think of a way to do this using `collect`, but you could use `Enumerable#bsearch_index`.

If `$days` is an integer, this does the same thing as your `if`; but it is not very readable. (Integer, because there is a slight problem that you are using two different comparisons, and I'm assuming `$days <= 20` is the same as `$days < 21`).

```
action_count[[0, 21].bsearch_index { |x| $days < x } || -1] += 1
```

`bsearch_index` finds whether `$days` is lower than `0`, `21` or neither, returning `0`, `1` or `nil`. We replace the `nil` case with `-1` (last element), and we have an index we can use to increment an appropriate element of `action_count`.

Comment: We can use `detect` or `find` too for the same, any specific reasons for using `bsearch_index`?

Comment: @Deep I like it. I'm more likely to use binary search when the array is sorted, although it doesn't really make a difference when the array is tiny. Any specific reasons for _not_ using it? (Also, you likely meant `find_index` instead, yes?)

Comment: Ah sorry `find_index` would only work here or else it will return the element. Thanks

Comment: @Amadan the array must be sorted for binary search, it's not optional.

Comment: @Stefan I know. I meant, if I have a sorted array, I am more likely to use binary than linear search (as an answer to why I used binary search here), and I definitely did not mean that when I use binary search I am more likely to have a sorted than unsorted array. I can see how that could have been misinterpreted though.

Comment: @Amadan oh I see 

Comment: I found your answer both interesting and useful. Just a note that if the breakpoints could be floats (in which case you couldn't use `$days < 21`) you could write `idx = [0, 20].bsearch_index { |x| $days <= x } || -1; idx = 1 if $days = 0; action_count[idx] += 1`.  For `$days` equal to `-5`, `0`, `10`, `20` and `25`, `idx` (after `idx = 1 if $days = 0`) respectively equals `0`, `1`, `1`, `1` and `-1`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Sure; but in that case I'd much prefer having the `if...elsif` thing. If all the cases are uniform, there's some benefit to brevity; if not, there is none (and brevity itself is lost).